# Hazelcast topic - messages seem to be sent from only one member

Tags: java, distributed-computing, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast cluster in client server mode. There are two members in the cluster.

From one client, I am publishing messages to topic and from other clients  I am trying to receive messages from the topic.

In management center , it is shown that all operations are performed in only one instance.

[image]

Is this the expected behavior ? I would expect publishes and receives in both members

Regards

Comment: ..i think, you'd have to increase the count of clients to see some effect, and of course it is all configurable (with defaults) [@see](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Hazelcast_Clients/Java_Client/Configuration/Load_Balancer.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see same question is answered on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/hazelcast/2OM-BjLE30U/XkIg1SmUBQAJ). As an addition to that answer, please keep in mind that ITopic is a non-partitioned data structure which means it is stored on a single partition (=single member). That's why you see all pub/sub related to that topic happens on a single member.

On the other hand, if you have a topic use-case I'd like to let you know about [ReliableTopic](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9.2/manual/html-single/#reliable-topic) as well, it has better guarantees but that might come with an overhead, obviously.